# Get-ADUser Working in Terminal, but not in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

When trying to create an array in a variable using Get-ADUser to get a user's groups in the terminal I get what I expect (a list of the groups).  But, as soon as I put the same command in a script I get a `Cannot find an object with identity` error.

With this command:

```
$members = @(((Get-ADUser -Identity BlueF -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf | Get-ADGroup).Name | Sort-Object)
```

In the terminal I get this:

```
$members
Group1
Group2
Group3
```

But, with the script I get this:

```
Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=Group1,OU=Company,DC=fqdn,DC=com' under: 'DC=fqdn,DC=com'.
At C:\search.ps1:1 char:89
+ ... Identity BlueF -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf | Get-ADGroup).Name | ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=Group1,DC=fqdn,DC=com:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

---

(from comment)

I'm using Powershell 5.1 (for work reasons). I've tried rebooting, no change. I used your suggestion of using a for loop and it did continue, but the $members returned empty. After messing around with this for far too long (over a day) I ended up just using

```
$members = @((((Get-ADUser -Identity $BlueF -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf) -replace '(.+?),.+','$1') -replace 'CN=','' | Sort-Object)
```

Not as elegant, but it will do for just making a list.

Comment: I cannot recreate your problem.  Using an Identity that is valid for my situation, I was able to run the script version without issue.  I tried this in both PS 5.1 and PS 7.3.8.  Some thoughts on troubleshooting: In a script, you might save the results of MemberOf and trying each one, one at a time, pipe to Get-ADGroup.  I assume the script died on the first error (which was Group1), so it would be interesting to know if it dies on any other group, or on all of the other Groups.  Also, as stupid as this may seem, try restarting your computer and see if the problem persist.

Comment: I'm using 5.1 (for work reasons).  I've tried rebooting, no change.  I used your suggestion of using a for loop and it did continue, but the $members returned empty.  After messing around with this for far too long (over a day) I ended up just using ```$members = @((((Get-ADUser -Identity $BlueF -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf) -replace '(.+?),.+','$1') -replace 'CN=','' | Sort-Object)``` Not as elegant, but it will do for just making a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the Get-ADGroup like this $(Get-ADGroup). I've found this works with similar errors I've received.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still getting the error wrapping it.